# Dropzone Ui Square Not Showing

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

my Dropzone Ui Default not showing after upload. 
The container is also not showing up.
Dropzone css file is working fine, but I don't know why this happening.
 It has been 3 hour II trying to solve it by myself.[image]

Answer (score 1):

seems like your Dropzone css is not imported. Please import Dropzone CSS CDN/File.

This is what dropzone CDN looks like (choose correct version): `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/basic.min.css`.

> If this doesn't Solve the issue. please share some code so we can have
> a good idea of what's the issue.

Comment: it seem like i forgot to add (Class at dropzone form ) I  only give Form Id , I am just too dump trying to figure out for almost 3 hour )